# CWWMQ0062E: Error receiving while enable SSL from IBM Queue Connection factories

Tags: java, ssl, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I have a process that uses connection factories and queues from IBM WebSphere. Both queues and connection factories are created on WebSphere.

My Process is working fine without SSL.

However when enabling SSL from WebSphere connection factory the following error is showing:

```
CWWMQ0062E: An SSL alias was provided with name ' '. However no SSL alias with this name exists.
CWWMQ0064E: It was not possible to create an SSLSocketFactory.  The provided port number was null.  The provided host name was null.  The provided SSL alias was ' '.
```

Any help how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How specifically did you enable SSL?

Comment: Hii, from websphere console in queues connection factory there is a check box to enable ssl with your own ssl created before.

Comment: Do you believe you have provided the port number, host name and SSL alias that the error message reports as null/blank? If so can you update your question with details.

Comment: Yes, without SSL is working fine. Once i have enabled the ssl it is showing this error.

Comment: Without SSL you would not need a SSL alias,  so you really didn't answer @MoragHughson's question. What version of WAS is the application deployed on? What version of IBM MQ is the queue manger you connect t to running?

Comment: And you need to exchange certificates between WebSphere and MQ (add them in the keystores).